# pandas set value if dates are the same in two diffrent df according to dates range

Tags: python, pandas

I have df:
while disease is binary column ( 0 or 1)

```
diagnosis_date    id  disease
2013-05-03         1     0
2013-05-08         1     0
2013-06-08         1     1
2013-01-01         2     0 
.....
```

and I have range of dates- 2013-01-01 until 2013-12-31:

```
date_index=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2013', end='31/12/2013')
dates=pd.DataFrame(date_index,columns=['date'])
```

I want for each id in df, to set the date range as date_index, and if the date is the same as diagnosis date, to set the value like it in the disease column, otherwise the value will be set to zero.
**the desire df:**

```
date    id    disease
01-01    1       0
02-01     1      0
03-01     1      0
...
05-03     1      0
05-04     1      0
...
06-08    1      1
 ....
12-31     1      0
01-01     2      1
01-02     2      0 
...
```

Thanks

Comment: date `05-03` has disease as `0` in original df and `1` in desired df? Is that expected?

Comment: my bad, I fix it

Comment: how many different id do you have?

Comment: Do you want to match on ID and date or just date between the dfs and populate disease?

Comment: I have 74 different id. I want to match according to id and date. for each id first set all the dates range (all days in 2013), and when the date meet 'diagnosis_date', set the value according to the 'disease' column in df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
date_index=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2013', end='31/12/2013')
dates = pd.DataFrame()
for i in df.id.unique():
    dates=pd.concat([dates,pd.DataFrame({'date':date_index, 'id' : np.full(len(date_index),i)})])
df.diagnosis_date = pd.to_datetime(df['diagnosis_date'])
df1 = pd.merge(dates,df, left_on=['id','date'], right_on=['id','diagnosis_date'], how='left')[['date','id','disease']].fillna(0)
df1['disease'] = df1.disease.astype(int)
```

Tested and prints correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
df = pd.read_clipboard() #read in your dataframe from clipboard

dfp = df.pivot('diagnosis_date', 'id', 'disease') #reshape dataframe
dfp.index = pd.to_datetime(dfp.index) #cast index to datetime

dfp.reindex(pd.date_range('1/1/2013','12/31/2013'))\  #add rows with reindex and pd.date_range
   .rename_axis('date').fillna(0)\  #fill with zeroes
   .stack().rename('disease')\  #Reshape back to original shape
   .reset_index()\
   .sort_values(['id', 'date'])  #and sort
```

Output:

```
          date  id  disease
0   2013-01-01   1      0.0
2   2013-01-02   1      0.0
4   2013-01-03   1      0.0
6   2013-01-04   1      0.0
8   2013-01-05   1      0.0
..         ...  ..      ...
721 2013-12-27   2      0.0
723 2013-12-28   2      0.0
725 2013-12-29   2      0.0
727 2013-12-30   2      0.0
729 2013-12-31   2      0.0
```

Comment: Yeah... but, I wanted to fill those existing NaN with zeroes too.  Hence, I used fillna after the reindex to catch all NaNs.

Comment: right because other Nan comes from the pivot, my bad